# Objective-C - Receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') is not an Objective-C class & Receiver type 'NSDecimal' is not an Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the errors in title and I have no idea why....

.h

```
@interface ItemData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger tagId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *deviceId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDecimal *latitude;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDecimal *longitude;


@end
```

.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ItemData.h"

@implementation ItemData

-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        //TODO: Fix Commented out items

        _tagId = [[NSInteger alloc] init];
        _deviceId = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        _latitude = [[NSDecimal alloc] init];
        _longitude = [[NSDecimal alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong...can someone help me out?

Comment: An NSInteger is not an object type, it is an intrinsic type like int or char.  You don't need to alloc/init it.  Similarly, NSDecimal is a struct, not a class, so again you don't alloc/init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInteger` and `NSDecimal` are no classes, but the type of scalars. You cannot sent messages to "objects" (in the sense of C, not in the sense of OOP) of this type. Therefore you do not construct them with `+alloc` and `-init…`.

You have two possibilities:

**A. Use (OOP) objects instead of scalars**

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSNumber *tagId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDecimalNumber *latitude;
```

Then you can assign references to objects as usual:

```
_tagId = @0; // Or whatever you want.
_latitude = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

**B. Simply assign a value**

```
_tagId = 0; // Or whatever you want. There is no nil for integers
```

This works good for integers, but bad for decimals, since they are a `struct` with private components and there is no function to create them. However, you can create an `NSDecimalNumber` instance object (as in A.) and get the decimal value with `-decimalValue`.

```
_latitude = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalValue];
```

The usage of `NSDecimal` seems to be erroneous for me. Why do you want to use it? Usually longitude and latitude are `double`, another scalar type, which can be treated as integers with values. Decimal floating point objects are for use in finance software.

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is

```
typedef long NSInteger;
```

That should explain "NSInteger (aka 'long')" and it is equivalent
 64-bit long (long int) C data type. It is not an OC class, that's why you can't do (+)alloc and (-)init.